# How can I prevent Pycharm's renaming function to modify library modules?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a class named `Error`. When I try to rename it with `Ctrl+F6`, PyCharm wants to also rename any `Error` appearances in library moudles, too. Is there a way to limit the scope in which PyCharm looks for occurences of `Error`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the project tree and mark your source code as "sources" and external libraries as "excluded".

[image]